# Condition to pass the parameter inside the list

Tags: c#

I don't know how to do the if check condition inside my list,i believe "Lambda Expressions" my help but don't know

here is my code

```
List<ResourceBookingEntity> ResourceBookingList = new List<ResourceBookingEntity>();
foreach (var r in query)
{
    ResourceBookingEntity RecourceEntity = new ResourceBookingEntity()
    {

        PRJ_ID = r.PRJ_ID,
        WONUM = r.WONUM,
        JOBDESC = r.JOBDESC,
        SAPCCr = // If r.PRJ_ID =1 or 2 then SAPCCr =r.WONUM 
                        // elseif r.PRJ_ID= 3then SAPCCr =r.JOBDESC
        };
    ResourceBookingList.Add(RecourceEntity);
```

Here what am trying to do,i have linq query that returns a result based on r.PRJ.ID value am trying to fill SAPCCr value.

```
If r.PRJ_ID = 1 or 2 then 
SAPCCr = r.WONUM 
elseif r.PRJ_ID = 3
then 
SAPCCr = r.JOBDESC
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain conditional operators:

```
SAPCCr = (r.PRJ_ID == 1 || r.PRJ_ID == 2) ?  r.WONUM :  
         r.PRJ_ID == 3 ?  r.JOBDESC : null;
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you're looking for the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
SAPCCr = r.PRJ_ID == 1 ? r.WONUM :r.JOBDESC
```

Comment: thanks a lot ob. exactly am looking this one but the problem is i have more than one codition and forgot to add it in my question.updated my question with the condition.

Comment: @Usher rather than making your code unreadable by trying to do this inline, consider writing a function to return the value you want `SAPCCr = GetValueFromResult(r);`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming types are compatible, what's wrong with the ternary conditional operator?

```
SAPCCr = ((r.PRJ_ID == 1) ? r.WONUM : r.JOBDESC );
```